# How to join Multi-level dataframe on values in single-level dataframe

Tags: pandas, join, dataframe, merge, multi-index

what I have so far is a normal transactional dataframe with the following columns:

```
store | item | year | month | day | sales
```

'year' can be 2015, 2016, 2017.

With that I created a summary dataframe:

```
store_item_years = df.groupby(
['store','item','year'])['sales'].agg(
[np.sum, np.mean, np.std, np.median, np.min, np.max]).unstack(
fill_value=0)
```

The last one results in a Multi-Index with 2 levels, like this:

```
               sum                  mean
        year | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | ... 
store | item   sum1    ...   ...    mean1  mean2  ...  | ...
```

Now I'd like to merge the summary table back onto the transactional one:

```
store | item | year | month | day | sales | + | sum+'by'+year | mean+'by'+year
               2015                              sum1              mean1
               2016                              sum2              mean2
               2017                              ...                ...
```

I am trying to merge with the following:

```
df = pd.merge(df, store_item_years, 
             left_on=['store', 'item', 'year'], 
             right_on=['store', 'item', 'year'],
             how='left')
```

which results in the following error:

```
KeyError: 'year'
```

Any ideas? I am just getting my head around groupby. I haven't looked into PivotTable yet.

Please keep in mind that the problem is simplified. The number of store_item combinations is 200+K and other groupbys having 300+ columns. But always the same principle.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first remove `unstack` and then use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for left join:

```
store_item_years = df.groupby(
['store','item','year'])['sales'].agg(
[np.sum, np.mean, np.std, np.median, np.min, np.max])

df = df.join(store_item_years, on=['store','item','year'])
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I just noticed it as well. I will accept your answer since you beat me to mine :)

Answer (score 0):

found the culprit. Removed .unstack().

```
store_item_years = df.groupby(
   ['store','item','year'])['sales'].agg(
   [np.sum, np.mean, np.std, np.median, np.min, np.max])
```

The following to keep the context:

```
store_item_years.columns = store_item_years.columns+'_by_year'
```

And merge like this:

```
pd.merge(df, store_item_years.reset_index(), 
         left_on=['store', 'item', 'year'], 
         right_on=['store', 'item', 'year'],
         how='left')
```